# Java Dynamic Table

Tags: jsp, servlets

```
<table border="1" bgcolor='white'>
                    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="component" varStatus="var">
                        <tr>
                            <td><c:out value="${component.compName}"></c:out></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="comp_${component.compId}"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="save" onclick="populateHiddenFields()"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                </table>
```

How to get the input type values in servlet..
along with component id and component value

Comment: What do you mean by input type? because all the parameters are ```String``` when us access through ```request.getParameter()```

Comment: how to take the text field values from the jsp page